# Pip install error exit status 1 while installing a pip package

Tags: python, pip, nlp, spacy

I'm having an issue while trying to install the `pyresparser` python library. The issue seems to be regarding a Spacy library. How could I solve this and install successfully ? I am a rookie on python

```
C:\Users\User>pip install pyresparser
Collecting pyresparser
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/8f/5a55cfb269621d3374a6ba4aed390267f65bdf6c4fed8b1c0cbf5a118f0e/pyresparser-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna>=2.8 (from pyresparser)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 261kB/s
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.15.2 (from pyresparser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/66/b2638d96a2d128b168d0dba60fdc77b7800a9b4a5340cefcc5fc4eae6295/pyrsistent-0.15.4.tar.gz
Collecting thinc>=7.0.4 (from pyresparser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/39/ea2a3d5b87fd52fc865fd1ceb7b91dca1f85e227d53e7a086d260f6bcb93/thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz
Collecting blis>=0.2.4 (from pyresparser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
Collecting tqdm>=4.32.2 (from pyresparser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/3d/7a6b68b631d2ab54975f3a4863f3c4e9b26445353264ef01f465dc9b0208/tqdm-4.32.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2019.6.16 (from pyresparser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/1b/b853c7a9d4f6a6d00749e94eb6f3a041e342a885b87340b79c1ef73e3a78/certifi-2019.6.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spacy>=2.1.4 (from pyresparser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/04/f25cdc3cb6d143ef397c23718026aff606c3e558cbd4939e9e4cb0a4b515/spacy-2.1.7.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kc70rx4b\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (70 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/51/f45cea425fd5cb0b0380f5b0f048ebc1da5b417e48d304838c02d6288a1e/setuptools-41.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/08/4f0d09d63b713955f9c6937923f1b1432331f468912b65824b19b9d82d19/Cython-0.29.13-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/cb/4ff546a491f764f67284572d25c57927e3f17103adf979bc99d90128f3eb/cymem-2.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/52/ef641ebb40e287b95e9742e7f3120dca0350d92b3d0ef050e5133acf8931/preshed-2.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e9/411be1845f1ac07ae3bc40a4b19ba401819baed4fa63b4f5ef28b2300eb4/murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/39/ea2a3d5b87fd52fc865fd1ceb7b91dca1f85e227d53e7a086d260f6bcb93/thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/c1/d76ccdd12c716be79162d934fe7de4ac8a318b9302864716dde940641a79/wasabi-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/59/6f276ab6d74888eed0e999d617101ed7357fc1ee073e9aac92d53260bd23/srsly-0.0.7.tar.gz
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/3f/d75fc983cc420b2acb5fae446b950e2dc9e5395a79fa76859d2528352d2c/numpy-1.17.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/3d/7a6b68b631d2ab54975f3a4863f3c4e9b26445353264ef01f465dc9b0208/tqdm-4.32.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
    Running setup.py install for murmurhash: started
      Running setup.py install for murmurhash: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n2rjetmh\\murmurhash\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n2rjetmh\\murmurhash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kburc6xm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kc70rx4b\overlay' --compile
           cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n2rjetmh\murmurhash\
      Complete output (35 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\tests\test_against_mmh3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\mrmr.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\mrmr.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\include
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\include\murmurhash\MurmurHash2.h -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\include\murmurhash\MurmurHash3.h -> build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
      running build_ext
      building 'murmurhash.mrmr' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-3.7
      creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n2rjetmh\murmurhash\murmurhash\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /EHsc /Tpmurmurhash/mrmr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash/mrmr.obj /Ox /EHsc
      mrmr.cpp
      murmurhash/mrmr.cpp(1199): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
      murmurhash/mrmr.cpp(1680): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n2rjetmh\murmurhash\murmurhash\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /EHsc /Tpmurmurhash/MurmurHash2.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash/MurmurHash2.obj /Ox /EHsc
      MurmurHash2.cpp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n2rjetmh\murmurhash\murmurhash\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /EHsc /Tpmurmurhash/MurmurHash3.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash/MurmurHash3.obj /Ox /EHsc
      MurmurHash3.cpp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86" /LIBPATH:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_mrmr build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash/mrmr.obj build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash/MurmurHash2.obj build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash/MurmurHash3.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.7\murmurhash\mrmr.cp37-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\murmurhash\mrmr.cp37-win32.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\SDK\\ScopeCppSDK\\VC\\bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n2rjetmh\\murmurhash\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n2rjetmh\\murmurhash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kburc6xm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kc70rx4b\overlay' --compile Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kc70rx4b\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I searched posts that show a similar issue, and tried some of the solutions but still can't fix it and install successfully.  How can I ensure a smooth and successful install regarding this Spacy library ? 
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Have you tried updating pip?

Comment: And have you got Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Have you googled the actual error `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'`? There are a few different answers you might want to check first. Some about reconfiguring VS, some about disabling Spectre Mitigation in your Windows settings.

Comment: @JammyDodger I did updated the pip and having the visual studio c++ build tool as well, but the problem still exist while installing the spacy

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried it but the problem still can't solve

Comment: any solution? having similar problems