# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output - while installing auto-py-to-exe through pip

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I am trying to download auto-py-to-exe on a different (windows) device than I usually use through pip. However when run I get the error (sorry it is so very very long):

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aplljhe0\\gevent\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aplljhe0\\gevent\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aplljhe0\gevent\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aplljhe0\gevent\
    Complete output (113 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-29et0so1\cffi-1.14.0\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
        HUB_PRIMITIVES = Extension(name="gevent.__hub_primitives",
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-29et0so1\cffi-1.14.0\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
        include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aplljhe0\gevent\setup.py", line 427, in <module>
        run_setup(EXT_MODULES, run_make=_BUILDING)
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aplljhe0\gevent\setup.py", line 328, in run_setup
        setup(
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-29et0so1\cffi-1.14.0\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
        HUB_PRIMITIVES = Extension(name="gevent.__hub_primitives",
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-29et0so1\cffi-1.14.0\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
        include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
      File "c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Even though it does state that I need Visual Studio C++ 14.0 my computer **won't install it** and I have **not needed it before**. I checked [This Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360687/pip-install-error-exit-status-1-while-installing-a-pip-package) but it relates to another pip install and has no answers. If the only answer is to install Visual Studio then I am kinda screwed.

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: pip install auto-py-to-exe @Kalana

Comment: What is your python version

Comment: My python version is idle - 3.8 32bit @Kalana

Comment: Ok I look back at this question 9 months later and it has 18 upvotes with around 80k views! That's big :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Edit

Since this answer was posted, `gevent` has released several new versions, including prebuilt wheels for Python 3.8 on Windows, so the `pip install gevent --pre` shouldn't be necessary anymore - just run `pip install auto-py-to-exe` as usual and it should work.

#### Original answer

Allow prerelease `gevent` versions via

```
$ pip install gevent --pre
$ pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Explanation: `auto-py-to-exe` is installable on Python 3.8 on Windows without any issues (this can be verified e.g. by running `pip install auto-py-to-exe --no-deps`). However, it requires `bottle-websocket` to be installed, which in turn has `gevent` dependency. `gevent` did not release a stable version that offers prebuilt wheels for Python 3.8 yet (this would be 1.5), so `pip` doesn't pick up prebuilt wheels and tries to build `gevent==1.4` from source dist. Installing the prerelease 1.5 version of `gevent` avoids this.

Comment: Wow this works so well - thanks. almost makes me wonder if I needed to put bounty on it at all...

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't know whether you can cancel a running bounty, but if you do, I don't mind.

Comment: The second pip install returned the same error for me (Check the logs for full command output.)

Comment: @dekio since I have written my answer, `gevent` has released prebuilt wheels for Python 3.8, so the `pip install gevent --pre` command shouldn't be necessary anymore. If you have _another_ setup (e.g. Python 3.9 instead of 3.8 etc or have installed the 32bit version of Python instead of 64bit), please open a new question describing your issue.

Answer (score 12):

In your problem, there are two problems occurred

1. `IndexError: list index out of range`.
2. `distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`

---

For the first error, You can try this code

```
pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute
```

if `--no-use-wheel` part didn't work, use `--no-binary :all:` instead.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901687/pip-install-broken-pkg-resources-find-distribution-returns-empty-list-in-req-py)

---

For the second error, you can use

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

---

## If the above methods didn't work

1. If your build tools further not answering to your problem, try to install build tools manually through this [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe?fixForIE=.exe).
2. After that you have to restart your PC or laptop.
3. Then try to run your code again

Comment: When I run pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute I get no such option: --no-use-wheel

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Source
'Source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: try to use `pip3` instead of `pip`. And also refer both source links. There are lot of suggestions in there

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute

Usage:
  pip3 install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip3 install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip3 install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip3 install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip3 install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --no-use-wheel

Comment: upgrade your `pip` and after that use pip3

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even after applying both options :(

Comment: `no such option: --no-use-wheel`

Comment: @alper try `--no-binary :all:` instead. [Source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/).

Answer (score 3):

for installing GDAL on mac:

`brew install gdal`
and then
`pip install gdal`
solved this for me

Comment: What does this command really do? Mine has run for now 30 minutes downloading files i have no idea of...it gets really annoying given i have no idea what it actually does ....pouring this and that then back to downloading

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while installing mysqlclient. Here is the solution in simple steps:

Step 0: `sudo apt install python3-dev build-essential`

Step 1: `sudo apt install libssl1.1`

Step 2: `sudo apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2`

Step 3: `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Step 4: `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

Step 5: `pip3 install mysqlclient`

That's it!