# I am facing "from setuptools import find_namespace_packages" error in python-2.7 while trying to install dm-sonnet package. Any possible solution?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I need to use python-2.7 for some script, setuptools==39.1.0, I cannot pip install dm-sonnet, is there supposed to be find_namespace_packages inside setuptools? Its not there in this setuptools(or v44)
Error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /home/russo/anaconda3/envs/russo2/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9l072x/dm-sonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9l072x/dm-sonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-9l072x/dm-sonnet/pip-egg-info
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9l072x/dm-sonnet/
        Complete output (5 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-install-9l072x/dm-sonnet/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
            from setuptools import find_namespace_packages
        ImportError: cannot import name find_namespace_packages
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs . In my question about this the answer did not help me but maybe it will help you

Comment: Is there a way to download from pip or use Python3

Comment: @JackAdee I used pip to install, and I need to use python2.7 for some particular scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dm-sonnet` requires Python 3](https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet/blob/941f7b331f040e96ea7cbae4d932fce9c1ba866c/setup.py#L59). You cannot use it with Python 2.

In the commit [00612ca](https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet/blob/00612ca3178964d86b556e062694d808ff81fcca/setup.py) `setup.py` uses [`find_packages`](https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet/blob/00612ca3178964d86b556e062694d808ff81fcca/setup.py#L25). You can try this version with Python 2.7. It's perhaps release [1.36](https://pypi.org/project/dm-sonnet/1.36/#files) or earlier. Try

```
pip2 install dm-sonnet==1.36
```

or

```
pip2 install 'dm-sonnet<2'
```