# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. How to fix the error?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I was trying to install auto-py-to-exe. 
And I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

I used both `pip install auto-py-to-exe`
and `python -m pip install auto-py-exe`

Comment: I am getting the same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs .My question has some suggestions that may help you even though they have not helped me yet - there is a set bounty at the current time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg\_info Check the logs for full command output - while installing auto-py-to-exe through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs)

Answer (score 0):

The user @hoefling answered my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs/61144180#61144180) and there are no more errors. You need to install gevent. In cmd (I advise running as administrator) type `pip install gevent` and then type `pip install auto-py-to-exe`. [gevent PYPI webpage](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/).