# Windows 10 Error Deploying to Heroku, Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, heroku

Beginner here.

Trying to deploy my Python code to heroku when I encounter the error below
My machine runs on Windows 10.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs) but no progress.

Let me know what other info that you need!

```html
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/pip-egg-info
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/
remote:            Complete output (15 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                import rtree
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
remote:                from .index import Rtree
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
remote:                from . import core
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-9bupgo_6/Rtree/rtree/core.py", line 145, in <module>
remote:                rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
remote:                func = self.__getitem__(name)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
remote:                func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
remote:            AttributeError: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command o
```

Comment: might this help? https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/135  do you have libspatialindex?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, still showing the same error...