# pip/pip3 install kivy not working in terminal (edited)

Tags: python, terminal, kivy

from what Ive tried Kivy is the only library i cant install, ive tried pip install kivy and pip3 install kivy heres the error.

error
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ouhC90oO2AdTLmisFlzN8EVPEEzRsu-AbgIm9V980eA/edit

(its to long to post here)
this error is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs) but the solution does not work and i get the same error.

Comment: please add the error/traceback directly here, not via an external link

Comment: its to long so wont allow me. here's the last sentence ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in cmd:

```
python -m pip install kivy==2.0.0rc1
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watchv=bMHK6NDVlCM&list=PLHU4Ue3mC6j7n5DuLVYao09hZx0tgOIGZ

Answer (score 1):

I think, you cannot install kiwy just through "pip install kivy"
Here are the installation instructions.
You need "Installing the kivy stable release"

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: ive now followed all of the instructions and ran all the commands in cmd but i still cant download it, i was able to download it through anaconda and move it to python scripts which also didn't work.