# Hello if I want to install python module hexdump make this error how is fix it?

Tags: python, pip, hexdump

```
pip install hexdump
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting hexdump
  Downloading hexdump-3.3.zip (12 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-YtkPKB/hexdump/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-YtkPKB/hexdump/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-TeQlQ3
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-YtkPKB/hexdump/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg\_info Check the logs for full command output - while installing auto-py-to-exe through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
We expect you to do appropriate research before posting here.  This includes bothering to look up the error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+invalid+command+egg_info

Answer (score 0):

```
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Trey installing setup tools